# How can I get my CodePipeline pipeline to update my resources using GitHub as the source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-cloudformation, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline

My goal is to push updates to GitHub and have it automatically update my resources in AWS.

I created a pipeline that uses GitHub as a source and it pushes the code to Cloudformation.

I tested the setup of my pipeline by pushing a changed template to github. Cloudformation shows the updated stack, but the resource is still the same. specifically, I added an additional attribute to the packaged-template.yaml file for my dynamodb table. in cloudformation i see that they packaged-template file has been updated but my dynamodb table is still the same.

I want a CI/CD model.

Comment: "Cloudformation shows the updated stack, but the resource is still the same. " Can you check events log in CFN. It should list exactly what was updated, if any.

Comment: The CFN events log show that the table was updated.
2020-06-27 17:22:15 UTC-0400 TestDynamodb UPDATE_COMPLETE

Comment: So it was updated. Thus can you clarify why you think it does not work?

Comment: I would guess maybe the yaml file used was incorrectly formatted?

Comment: If it was incorrectly format, the updated wouldn't be successful.

Comment: `- AttributeName: T2
        AttributeType: N`
This is what i added to the packaged-template file. My table still only shows T1.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say. `UPDATE_COMPLETE` means update was successful. Did you expect different outcome?

Comment: I expected to see the additional attribute (T2) in my table, but after future research and testing I understand that the tables don't work the way that I thought. I need to go a different route when updating tables. 
I was able to successfully update my API so I understand that the pipeline works. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference. It's acceptance would be appreciated if my help was useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

It was determined that the pipepine and CloudFormation **updates worked correctly**. However, due to the nature of how DynamoDb works (i.e. it has non-fixed attributes, except primary key and sort key), **new approach** is going to be used for the use case at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have pushed to the branch on GitHub that you referenced in your source actions.

Assuming you did push to this branch please make sure that your token has the following permissions:

- `repo`
- `admin:repo_hook`

Assuming these all work, try to invoke it manually. If it can get the source data and execute then your permissions allow to pull from GitHub, meaning something is wrong with the trigger.

More information on setting up the GitHub permissions available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-GitHub.html#action-reference-GitHub-example).